# Armature not moving with mesh

Tags: armature

https://mega.nz/file/2lQGjD6T#YIr1GouvxZlPXPB_FL1qWfF1fShevNgNnRCrYO5wIC4

i tried everything but ive been trying to parent the mesh to the armature but nothing works

(the file was made in 2.79 and i tried this both in 2.8 because this is for a game)
(this has weights)

if anybody can help i would love it[image]

Comment: it looks like it's impossible to parent With Automatic Weight, probably due to your topology, I guess you first need to merge by distance to avoid any overlapping etc

Answer (score 0):

Check that the armature modifier is active on your mesh.

check that the armature name is correct, check that there are vertex groups that match your bone names and check that the bones in your rig are set to deform.  Or it may be because your armature in object mode is moved off center and rotated.

Comment: alright i figured it out but i want to parent it with the models built in weights i tried looking up how to transfer the weights before but i really don't want to weight paint since i have tried it before and it was a drag that didn't even work i tried it two times actually

Comment: it only works with with automatic weights when i want empty groups